# Button that leads to report: how to have a single one that works in Classic as well as in Lightning?

Tags: lightning, urlhacking, classic

I have a button on a Contact detail page, which leads to a report specific for the displayed Contact:

```
{!URLFOR('/00O58000004S13g', null, [pv0=Contact.Id])}
```

However, this does not work in Lightning, there it needs to be like this:

```
{!URLFOR( '/lightning/r/Report/00O58000004S13gEAC/view?fv0=' + Contact.Id )}
```

So how do I make one button that works in both Classic and Lightning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulas that can used in button URLs allow for many things, making this expression possible:

```
{!IF($User.UIThemeDisplayed="Theme4d",
URLFOR('/lightning/r/Report/00O58000004S13gEAC/view?fv0=' + Contact.Id),
URLFOR('/00O58000004S13g', null, [pv0=Contact.Id])
)}
```

The button with this URL can be used both in Classic and in Lightning, which is quite useful when not all users can make the transfer to Lightning.